# sympy regression example, solve after partial derivative

Tags: matrix, regression, sympy, symbolic-math, derivative

I try to solve some matrix calculus problem with sympy and get stuck at the solver after differentiation with respect to a vector.

As a short example let's take ordinary least squares regression.
E.g. the sum of the squared differences between target y and prediction y_hat. Where the prediction `y_hat = X.T * w` is linear combination and thus a matrix vector multiplication.

We therefore want to minimize the LMS Error with respect to the weight vector w.

By hand we can derive that from:

```
Err(w) = norm(y - X.T * w)^2
```

follows after differentiation, setting to zero and solving for w

```
w_opt = (X*X.T)^-1 * X * y
```

How can we derive w_opt using sympy?

My rather naïve approach was:

```
from sympy import *
# setup matrix and vectors
X = MatrixSymbol('X',3,5)
y = MatrixSymbol('y',5,1)
w = MatrixSymbol('w',3,1)

# define error function
E = (y - X.T*w).T * (y - X.T*w) 
# derivate
Edw = [E.diff(wi) for wi in w]
# solve for w
solve(Edw,w)
```

At `solve(Edw,w)` however i get the attribute error: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'shape'

I also tried to set `E.as_explicit()` before differentiating. This however resultet in the attribute error: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_Piecewise'

I know by calculating by hand, that after derivation the result should be `-2*X*y + 2*X*X.T*w`. The derivation in `Edw` is listed but not performed. How can I verify this step in between? My first guess was the `.doit()` method, which unfortunately is not defined in that case.

Comment: Why differentiate? Why not use the directional derivative?

Comment: I understand the directional derivative to be the dot product of a directional vector with the gradient. I assume Edw to be the gradient. How would you proceed?